# no more raspberry icone on the left of the application bar

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, taskbar

I certainly made a mistake when 'improving' the (LXDE) application bar.
The raspberry on the left disappeared.

1. how can I restore it ?
2. more generally how can I restore the application bar as it was initially when installing Pi OS (without installing Pi OS of course) ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: how did you remove the icon? ... what does the icon represent?

Answer (score 1):

If you still have a Panel;
right-click the Panel
Add/Remove Panel items
Then Add and select Menu
Click on the Menu (in Panel Applets) then Preferences then set Icon "start-here" and set padding (usually 4)
Move Menu Up to the top (I like to have a Spacer as first item)

NOTE you can have multiple "Menu" items

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot,
I tried many things,
but at the end, I re-installed pi OS...
I am still wondering if there exist a way to put the launbch bar in its "initial" state. I tried to copy some configutaion files from another Pi OS, but unsuccessfully.
Best regards